# Call stored procedure in groovy and retrieve the OUT parameter and Cursor

Tags: groovy, groovy-sql

I have a Stored Procedure that returns a VARCHAR OUT and a Cursor. The rows is always null and I need the result set in it. How do I get it? I get the OUT value in iStatus as expected.

```
def rows = sql.call stmt, parameters, { it ->
   iStatus = it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Sql#callWithRows()](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#callWithRows(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) or [Sql#callWithAllRows()](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#callWithAllRows(groovy.lang.GString,%20groovy.lang.Closure)).

There are two variations for each of the methods. One with `GString` and the other with `List` of parameters.

It's quite new feature though so you may need to update Groovy version.